# typescript with require-js how to avoid specifing full path to file in require()

Tags: typescript, typescript1.4

I have 2 files:

baseVM.ts(in `bases` folder):

```
class BaseVM {
    a: string;
    data: any;
    constructor() {
        this.data = {};
    }
    getData() {
        return "Hi bros";
    }
}
export = BaseVM;
```

Example.ts(in `someFolder`)

```
import BaseVM = require("baseVM");
class Example extends BaseVM {
    controlModule: KnockoutObservable<Module>;
    data: PolicyOrderDTO;
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
export = Example;
```

and I have also configured require-config(require-config.ts):

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "Scripts/app",
    paths: {
        "baseModel": "/bases/baseVM",
        "Example":"/someFolder/Example"
    }
});

require(["Example"], (Example)=>{
   var example = new Example();
   example.getData();
});
```

But it dont build and show the error in `Example.ts` in line `import BaseVM = require("baseVM");`. It says that he cant find file, but to write always the full path is a bit annoying. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> but to write always the full path is a bit annoying

Sadly you need to specify full paths at the moment. IDEs can make it easier : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript#relative-paths

Also there is typescript issue tracking this : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2338

Comment: It is sad that after 3 years of typescript development there is still no normal integration with AMD... :(